# List of Java Object from Database with Slowness issues

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I'm working on a java code and all is fine but I'm starting to experiment some slowness issues in my GUI. This is my code :

```
//some code..
//get articles from database
//in this case listOfArticles  contains 1000 Objects
listOfArticles = service.getArticles();

//loop through listOfArticles to get another data from my database
for (Article article: listOfArticles) {

//each list may conatins 100 to 200 Objects
//in this case I'm going to the database 1000 times and this maybe the cause of the Slowness 
listOfInfo = service.getInfoById(article.getId());

//...some code
}
```

In the GUI I'm waiting between 20 s and 30 s to get the result, do you have any suggestion to optimise the response time or avoid going to the database inside my loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to break up the big list of articles into chunks and only fetch information about them in an on-demand fashion?

Comment: Images and such should not be in the object. When using JPA one would need to be careful what is gotten: heavier fields, like lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the number of database access populate a *List* with all *Article* id's and then create a method with the following signature (adapt to your needs):

```
public List<Info> getInfoByIds(List<Long> articleIdList)
```

That method should end up with a query that gets all *Info* objects in a single database access (example in JPQL):

```
select i from Info i where i.ID in :idList
```

Again, without knowing more about your code I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Well my answer my look quite vague but I would give you two advises:

1. Use [some pagination](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination) (ex display 50 items at once) or use some infinite scroll.
2. Use a method returning you several articles at once. (You can have a look at th example given by Bernat)